# Given two sets of coordinates, find out neighboring ones

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms, sets, image-processing

I have two sets of 2-dimensional coordinates on an integer grid, $A$ and $B$

$A = \{(x_{A1},y_{A1}), (x_{A2}, y_{A2}), (x_{A3}, y_{A3}), \dots\}$

$B = \{(x_{B1},y_{B1}), (x_{B2}, y_{B2}), (x_{B3}, y_{B3}), \dots\}$

I need to find all coordinates in $B$ that are directly above, below, or to the left or right of any coordinate in $A$.

So they differ by one of $\{(1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)\}$ from the matching coordinate(s) in $A$.

As an example,

$A = \{(0,0), (1,2), (2,2)\}$

$B = \{(0,1), (1,2), (0,3)\}$

would result in

$R = \{(0,1), (1,2)\}$

How can I efficiently do this?

Answer (score 2):

If the coordinates keep reasonable values and if you can afford marking the points in an image, start with an empty image, mark all $B$ pixels (takes $\#B$ pixel sets) and test all neighborhoods of the $A$ pixels (takes $4\times\#A$ pixel tests).

If you need to do this repeatedly, rather than clearing the image every time, better erase the $B$ pixels (another $\#A$ pixel sets).

Hard to make it faster.

---

Another solution is to sort both point sets in lexicographical order $y$ then $x$ using a linear-time sort (histogram sort). Then a simple merge pass will detect the common points.

But instead of using $A$ directly, replace every point in $A$ by its four Von Neumann neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

Store $B$ in a hashtable.

For each element of $A$, check whether it is in the hashtable.  Also, for each element of $A$, for each of its four neighbors, check whether that neighbor is in the hashtable.

The expected running time will be approximately $O(|A|+|B|)$.

---

If you want a further constant-factor speed-up, it is possible to speed this up even further, if $A,B$ are sparse.

Given a location $(x,y)$ in $A$, compute $x'= \lfloor x/2 \rfloor$, $y'=\lfloor y/2 \rfloor$, and then store $(x,y)$ in a hashtable keyed on $(x',y')$.  This basically breaks the grid up into $2 \times 2$ blocks, with all locations in the same $2 \times 2$ block treated identically and hashed identically.  Now given a location $(u,t)$ in $B$, you can find three $2 \times 2$ blocks that cover $(u,v)$ and its neighborhood.  So, look up those three blocks in the hashtable, check whether any of them contain any points in $A$, and if so, check whether they are in the neighborhood of $(u,v)$.  In the average case, you'll need to do about 3 hashtable lookups per point of $A$, rather than 5.

The expected running time is still $O(|A|+|B|)$, but the constant factor is reduced by about a ratio of $5/3$.

Comment: This is working well! Observing that either the x or y component are the same, this *may* still be more improved

Comment: @2080, see edited answer if you want one idea for a further improvement.

Comment: One thing I have to note is that same coordinates should not be retrieved, only the 4 bordering ones

Comment: @2080, if that's important, I suggest editing your question to state it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one-time comparison, or might there be a single *A* and multiple *B*s?

If the test is to be run on multiple *B*s, one could put more effort into analyzing *A* and greatly reduce the multiple look-up times.

For instance:

- First build a boolean table (array or hash) that is True for each member of *A*, and for each neighbor of *A*.
- For each *B*, simply check whether each element is in the table.

That's still $O(|A|+|B|)$, but processing each *B* will require only 1 lookup, not 5.